# Video not saving when I use the fourcc 'X264'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm new to opencv and ffmpeg so I don't know if this is a noob question. I'm writing a video with the following statement:

`out = cv2.VideoWriter('videoname.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))`

My program runs however, the video does not save. I tried looking for solutions online but none of them seem to work. What I have already tried:

1. It works correctly when I used `*'XVID'` or `*'MJPG'` but the file size is larger than what I require.
2. Using `0x00000021` as the fourcc argument
3. Trying variations of x264, X264, H264, h264 as I read it might be case sensitive. This also does not work.
4. Specifying the channel when installing ffmpeg with the command `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg` (even though I already have built ffmpeg from source, I tried this)
5. Trying to install x264 using `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev`. I get the following result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx264-dev is already the newest version (2:0.152.2854+gite9a5903-2).
x264 is already the newest version (2:0.152.2854+gite9a5903-2).
ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
```

Can someone help me where I could possibly be going wrong? **I require the video codec to be x264 when saving the video to get a small file size.**

Other info:
OpenCV version used: `4.2.0`
Platform: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: were you able to fix this issue. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: No I was not, it seems to be an issue that has not been fixed for a long time as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/223#issuecomment-285523938). I used the XVID codec as this gave the smallest video size among the available options.